# Which View Transform for most realistic Renderings that I want to Edit in Lightroom later anyway

Tags: color-management, filmic-blender

I am currently having difficulty deciding on the correct View Transform (Standard, Filmic, Agx). I want to create product renderings that are as realistic as possible. For this I would edit the renderings in Lightroom later according to my wishes anyway.

And here comes my big question:
From my unterstanding the View Transform is responsible for converting the render's internal, linear image values into values that are more suitable for display on a monitor.
I thought the new Agx View Transform would provide more image information compared to Standard or Filmic. However, the more I read into the subject, I have the feeling that it has no influence on the actual image data. So if I plan to do extensive editing of the images later, it is only important to work with a view transform that compresses the data less. But which View Transform compresses the least and is most suitable for post-processing?

Thanks so much for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be concerned about the file format rather than the view transform.

So long as you're saving to a format that only supports the 0,1 range of color, then you'll be compressing your color into that range.  Exactly how you compress will be determined by the view transform you choose, but they'll all be compressing your color into that range, and they're all "equal" compression in that sense.

But if you save your image as an .exr, Blender understands that you don't want to do any kind of view transform and saves the raw, linear data into that .exr.  So you can use the uncompressed data in some other application, and only ever apply a view transform at the end of some pipeline that Blender can't even guess at.

Comment: Hey Nathan, thanks a lot for this detailed answer. Funnily, i just watched this video, which supports your comment [link](https://youtu.be/-UjJqwwMJc8?si=jJmO4kla_MxG9yYq)